# Incorrect checksum for freed object on malloc

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I get an

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1001012f8: incorrect checksum for freed object
        - object was probably modified after being freed.
        *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

error in the following function:

```
char* substr(const char* source, const char* start, const char* end) {
    char *path_start, *path_end, *path;

    int path_len, needle_len = strlen(start);

    path_start = strcasestr(source, start);
    if (path_start != NULL) {
        path_start += needle_len;
        path_end = strcasestr(path_start, end);
        path_len = path_end - path_start;
        path = malloc(path_len + 1);
        strncpy(path, path_start, path_len);
        path[path_len] = '\0';
    } else {
        path = NULL;
    }

    return path;
}
```

How can I make this work? When I rewrite the function to allocate the memory using `path[path_len + 1]` it works just fine.

Now, the part I don't understand is, that I never even call `free` in any point of my application, as every allocated memory is needed for the program until it exists (which, AFAIK will invalidate every allocated memory anyway?!)

So, how can a freed object be corrupt if I never free one?

The function is called in this one:

```
char *read_response(int sock) {
    int bytes_read;
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    char *cur_position = buf;

    while ((bytes_read = read(sock, cur_position, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        cur_position += bytes_read;
        buf = realloc(buf, sizeof(buf) + BUF_SIZE);
    }

    int status = atoi(substr(buf, "HTTP/1.0 ", " "));
```

There is the `realloc`, am I using that wrong? I want to read the complete server response, so I have to reallocate after every iteration, don't I?

Comment: I don't see a `free()` anywhere in that code.

Comment: Well, I need the return value of that function in my code

Comment: Then you might want to post the code that eventually calls `free()` on that pointer.

Comment: I suspect some other part of your code frees something and modifies it after that point. So by the time *this* malloc shows up, the harm had already been done.

Comment: I don't, it's carried on until the application exists and I need the value until the very end.

Comment: doesn't look like the problem is here in this part of the code though

Comment: Come to realize it, I don't call `free()` once in my entire code. Every value I allocate is needed for the program to continue. So if I never free something, how can a freed object be compromised?

Comment: The error is suggesting that you messed up the heap by modifying a variable after freeing it, but that doesn't mean that's how you did it. What you're doing is messing up the heap.

Comment: @Florian: Easy: heap corruption. Some code could be overwriting vital parts that `malloc` and `free` use for book keeping. In fact it sounds just like that. Use Valgrind or DrMemory to help you spot the problem.

Comment: You just deleted your code, but before it was deleted I didn't see you checking for errors, such as strcasestr(path_start, end) returning NULL. Can you repost your code? I'm guessing that something along those lines is what's causing your error. Also, a tip for strings: use snprintf instead of strncpy and you won't have to add the path[path_len] = '\0' at the end. snprintf takes care of that for you.

Comment: Does your program calls `realloc`?

Comment: While this is not related to the error, you are still abusing `strncpy`. If you know exactly how many characters you need to copy, use `memcpy` or some sort of `strlcpy` at least. `strncpy` is completely out of place here, even if it "works".

Comment: I posted some more code that calls the function, also with a call to realloc in it, maybe this will help to clear things up?

Comment: I see a `realloc()`. That counts as a `free()`.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. But when thinking about it, it makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `read_response`, you are probably overwriting the end of the buffer pointed to by `buf`.

The problem is that buf is a pointer, so `sizeof(buf)` will return the size of a pointer (probably 4 or 8 depending on your CPU). You are using `sizeof` as if `buf` were an array, which is not really the same thing as a pointer in C although they seem interchangeable in some contexts.

Instead of using `sizeof`, you need to be keeping track of the last size that you allocated for `buf`, and add `BUF_SIZE` to that each time you enlarge the buffer.

You should also consider that the `read` operation may be returning considerably fewer characters than `BUF_SIZE` on each call, so doing a `realloc` on `buf` in each iteration may be overkill. That probably won't cause any problems for you in terms of correctness, though; it will just use more memory than it needs to.

I would do something more like the code below.

```
#define MIN_BUF_SPACE_THRESHOLD (BUF_SIZE / 2)

char *read_response(int sock) {
    int bytes_read;
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    int cur_position = 0;
    int space_left = BUF_SIZE;

    if (buf == NULL) {
        exit(1); /* or try to cope with out-of-memory situation */
    }

    while ((bytes_read = read(sock, buf + cur_position, space_left)) > 0) {
        cur_position += bytes_read;
        space_left -= bytes_read;
        if (space_left < MIN_BUF_SPACE_THRESHOLD) {
            buf = realloc(buf, cur_position + space_left + BUF_SIZE);
            if (buf == NULL) {
                exit(1); /* or try to cope with out-of-memory situation */
            }
            space_left += BUF_SIZE;
        }
    }
```

This version has the advantage of not trying to allocate more space if the `read` call comes back with only a few bytes of data.

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
buf = realloc(buf, sizeof(buf) + BUF_SIZE);
```

is wrong. All reallocations are with the same size, `BUF_SIZE + sizeof(char*)`. Then you are writing to unallocated memory when reading from the socket, overwriting memory previously `free`d by a `realloc`.

You have to keep track of the allocated size,

```
size_t current_buf_size = BUF_SIZE;
/* ... */
    char *temp = realloc(buf, current_buf_size + BUF_SIZE);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        /* die or repair */
    }
    buf = temp;
```

Comment: Oh... right... sizeof(char*) != strlen(char*). Should've known that. Will `strlen(buf) + BUF_SIZE` work correctly?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka `strlen(buf) + BUF_SIZE` may need a `+ 1` for 0-terminator, and it will only work if there is a 0-terminator in `buf`. `read` doesn't automatically add one.

Comment: Could you elaborate your example more? Maybe with the loop? I could really use a hint in that matter. How do I add the terminator at the end of the buffer after reading it in completely?

Comment: You can put in the 0-terminator easily, since you have `cur_position` to track the end. After `cur_position += bytes_read;` just insert a `*cur_position = 0;`, but make sure that there is space in the buffer for that. But If you use Nate C-K's example, you don't need the 0-terminator until after the loop. (For all string-handling functions, it is generally required. If your input is as expected, `int status = atoi(substr(buf, "HTTP/1.0 ", " "));` works even without 0-terminator, but for malformed input that can crash badly.)