# Get line of FILE *

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

I'm trying to learn C (which is freaking hard...) so I wanted to write a routine which gets a line of a file. I created this function :

```
int c;
int buflen = 100;
if((*buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * buflen)) == NULL) {
  DXLogWarn("Not enough memory");
  return;
}

char * dst = *buffer;
char * end = *buffer + buflen - 1;
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
  if (c == '\n') {
    break;
  }
  if (dst < end) {
    *dst++ = c;
  }  
}
*dst = '\0';
```

Which works yay! But now I thought instead of cutting of the last part of the string I could realloc the buffer and continue till the '\n'. So I changed it to this:

```
void fget_line(FILE *fp, char **buffer) {
int c;
int buflen = 10;
if((*buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * buflen)) == NULL) {
  DXLogWarn("Not enough memory");
  return;
}

char * dst = *buffer;
char * end = *buffer + buflen - 1;
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
  if (c == '\n') {
    break;
  }

  if (dst < end) {
    *dst++ = c;
  } else {
    buflen *= 2;
    *buffer = realloc(*buffer, buflen * sizeof(char));
    if (*buffer == NULL) {
      DXLogError("Err");
      return;
    }
  }

}
*dst = '\0';
}
```

Which gives me an error : malloc: *** error for object 0x10a8001b8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Which I do not get. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you google that error text - "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed"? There are some hits - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457932/incorrect-checksum-for-freed-object-on-malloc) for example.

Comment: Update your `end` variable also with each `realloc`

Comment: @sashoalm I do not completely understand those hits as I think ( probably not) i am keeping buffer size right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the start you do:

```
char * dst = *buffer;
char * end = *buffer + buflen - 1;
```

This set dst and end to the correct positions inside buffer. Then you reallocate buffer:

```
*buffer = realloc(*buffer, buflen * sizeof(char));
```

This causes buffer to get a new value which is probably different then before. So you also have to update `dst` and `end` to the new positions inside buffer.

Changing `end` is easy, but because you keep changing `dst`, it is difficult to calculate the new value. So instead of changing the pointers, it might be easier to store just the offset in a integer. Something like:

```
int pos=0;
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
  if (c == '\n') {
    break;
  }

  if (pos >= buflen-1) {
    buflen *= 2;
    *buffer = realloc(*buffer, buflen * sizeof(char));
    if (*buffer == NULL) {
      DXLogError("Err");
      return;
    }
  }

  (*buffer)[pos] = c;
  pos++;
}
(*buffer)[pos] = '\0';
```

I also changed the if statement above, as you did not store the character which caused the reallocation.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the problem and the solution! Super!